# SQL PHP INSERT INTO tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to INSERT INTO multiple tables for this?

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, feet, inche, weight, dob, college, pob, experience, cy, py
FROM player 
INNER JOIN attribute ON player.pid = attribute.pid
INNER JOIN history ON player.pid = history.pid
INNER JOIN salary ON player.pid = salary.pid
```

How do I join the tables for:

```
if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO player(first_name, last_name) VALUES (?, ?)"))){
   echo "Prepare for player failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}
if(!($stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['first_name'],$_POST['last_name']))){
    echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support multi-table insertion in a single INSERT statement

Comment: INSERT can happen only in one table at a time. You have to write multiple insert statement for inserting into more than one table.

Comment: Put a ; between insert statements, then it's kind of like one?

Comment: first your select is wrong! and secondly for inserting multiple entries you need to make an array and then pull it in one loop

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn’t support insert into multiple tables via single insert statement, I believe Oracle is only support it.

But you can use a `Transaction` to make sure all insert statements execute via single transaction.